# Power MB102 from a USB port in the computer

Tags: power-supply, embedded, breadboard

Just bought a MCU ESP-01 which requires maximum 3.3V and uses at peak 200mA. So to power my projects, I also acquired a breadboard power supply ([MB102](https://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_176805.html?vip=2665035&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgNrQBRC0ARIsAE-m-1yu56YGzC_IYEgwd3tYFOW144qhIX1Q3E3DETDLmX0lk3BJHUyErsYaAkckEALw_wcB)) which can output 5V and 3.3V simultaneously. It's powered by a 6.5 to 12V power source, either through a USB connector or the other connector (which I don't know the name).

[image]

The problem is that the MB102 requires an input source of at least 6.5V and I don't have any power supply to feed it. So my question is: Will it be enough to power the MB102 using a USB male-to-male cable connected to my computer USB port? I will only be using the 3.3V option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MB102 is a simple set of linear regulators. You can provide power via the DC or Barrel Jack, or via the USB connector. You could also use the 5V pin if you really wanted to. The USB port could also provide power out.

[image]

Based on that, you can provide power in via a non-standard usb male A to usb male A connector. (The non-standard cable here is a poor choice though imho.) The 3.3V regulator will then power your ESP board without issue.

Comment: So, will connecting the USB to a 5V power supply (in this case, the computer) be enough to power the ESP board?

Comment: Yes. The 6.5V requirement is related to the 5V voltage regulator. However, if you feed it from USB, the 5V regulator is bypassed. So the 6.5V requirement does not apply in this setup. It should still be able to produce 3.3V if you need it.